# Isomorphic subgroups of finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, permutations, computational-algebra

> Which is the smallest number $n$ such that $S_n$ has non-isomorphic
>   subgroups of the same order with the same number of cyclic subgroups
>   of the same order?

Example: $S_4$ has subgroups of order $4$ isomorphic to $Z_4$ and $Z_2\times Z_2$. 
Here $Z_4$ has only one cyclic subgroup of order $2$ 
while $Z_2\times Z_2$ has three cyclic subgroups of order 2, so the test with cyclic subgroups shows that $Z_4$ and $Z_2\times Z_2$ is *not* isomorphic.

The idea with the cyclic subgroup test is to make a first (fast) try to falsify that two finite groups of the same order are isomorphic - in [a set based system for computational algebra](http://forthmath.blogspot.se).

Unfortunately, set based group implementations are slow, so I can't make a systematic test, but have tested a lot of groups with same order so far without finding examples of non-isomorphic groups which fails in the test.

Comment: Can you clarify what "a lot of groups" constitutes?

Comment: $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2\;$ has *three*, not only two, subgroups of order two.

Comment: I believe I just wrote some GAP code which finds several examples of groups of order 16 which are non-isomorphic but have the same number of cyclic subgroups of every order.  For example, small group IDs [16,2], [16,4], and [16,12] all have the same number of cyclic subgroups of the same order.   These groups have structure description $C_4\times C_4, C_4\rtimes C_4,$ and $C_2\times Q_8$.

Comment: @Joanpemo, yes you are right.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: thank you! So I know that $n\leq 16$ then. Well, my system has a poor implementation of groups so far. I guess I have to learn GAP for reference requests...

Comment: @Lehs Actually, all of those groups should imbed into $S_{12}$, and two of them fit into $S_{10}$, so $n\leq 10$.  $C_4\times C_4$ easily fits into $S_8$; but $Q_8$ needs $n\geq 8$, so $C_2\times Q_8$ embeds into $S_{10}$; and as far as I can tell $C_4\rtimes C_4$ requires $n\geq 12$.  I've not yet figured out how to get GAP to actually decide the minimum $n$.  The main problem being that once $n\geq 7$ then $S_n$ starts having subgroups of orders too large to easily handle checks for isomorphism to other subgroups of that order.

Comment: @Lehs Done.  After a few tweaks I got around the $S_7$ issue, and proved the answer is $n=8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following GAP code will go through all groups of order 16 (which is easily changed to other orders in the small group package) and will find the number of every cyclic group of every order in each such group.  The values stored in `vallist` are a list of lists, where each entry gives the SmallGroup ID number for the relevant cyclic group in the first entry and the total number of copies of that cyclic subgroup as the second number.  It then adds the completed `vallist` as an element of `cyclist`.  So the `vallist` for `SmallGroup(16,4)`, for example, is the 4th entry of `cyclist`: `cyclist[4];`

```
cyclist := []; 

for G in AllSmallGroups(16) 
do 
    vallist := []; 
    subs := Filtered(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G),X->IsCyclic(Representative(X)));  
    subclasses := Set(List(subs,H->IdGroup(Representative(H)))); 
    for H in subclasses 
    do 
        subnumber := Sum(List(Filtered(subs,X->IdGroup(Representative(X))=H),Size)); 
        Add(vallist,[H,subnumber]); 
    od; 

    Add(cyclist,vallist);
od;
cyclist;
```

The final line just prints the entire contents of cyclist, and can be omitted.

Two groups will have the same number of cyclic subgroups of every order if and only if they yield the same `vallist`.  So you can perform various searches or logical tests to find all such groups.  For example

```
Positions(cyclist,cyclist[4]);
```

will spit out the positions in cyclist of every entry that is identical to `cyclist[4]`.  In this case the output should be

```
[2,4,12]
```

Meaning that SmallGroup(16,2), SmallGroup(16,4), and SmallGroup(16,12) all have the same number of cyclic subgroups of every order.  Applying the `StructureDescription` function to all of these yields, respectively

\begin{align*}
C_4\times C_4\\
C_4\rtimes C_4\\
C_2\times Q_8
\end{align*}

I'll note at this stage that this is not the only set of groups of order 16 which share this property.  The desired relation is clearly an equivalence relation, and the (non-singleton) classes can be computed via

```
Filtered(Set(List(cyclist,l->Positions(cyclist,l))),L->Length(L)>1);
```

yielding the output

```
[ [ 2, 4, 12 ], [ 3, 10, 13 ], [ 5, 6 ] ]
```

The first and last classes have two subgroups that can be embedded into $S_{10}$ (which can be proven by a few known facts, or using gap code such as what I'm about to use).  The second class, however, is much more interesting.  We can compute permutation representations of small degree for them and notice the highest number that appears to find the upper bound for the $S_n$ they each embed into.

```
 List([3,10,13],j->Image(SmallerDegreePermutationRepresentation(Image(IsomorphismPermGroup(SmallGroup(16,j))))));
```

yields

```
[ Group([ (1,2,4,6)(3,5,7,8), (2,5)(6,8), (1,3)(2,5)(4,7)(6,8), (1,4)(2,6)(3,7)(5,8) ]), 
Group([ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6,7,8) ]), 
Group([ (2,6)(5,8), (1,2)(3,5)(4,6)(7,8), (1,3,4,7)(2,5,6,8), (1,4)(2,6)(3,7)(5,8) ]) ]
```

Therefore, all three of these groups embed into $S_8$.  So we have an upper bound of $n\leq 8$.  Note that GAP does not guarantee that the degrees of the representations above are the actual minimum.

So what's a lower bound?

The following code is one way to check smaller symmetric groups for such subgroups.

```
    for n in [3..7]
    do
        G := SymmetricGroup(n);
        subgroups := Filtered(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G),X->Order(Representative(X))<Factorial(n)/2;
        subgroups := Set(List(subgroups,X->IdGroup(Representative(X))));

        testlist := [];

        for Hh in subgroups 
        do
            H := SmallGroup(Hh);
            vallist := [];

            cycsubs := Filtered(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(H),X->IsCyclic(Representative(X)));

            cyctypes := Set(List(cycsubs,X->IdGroup(Representative(X))));

            for K in cyctypes
            do
                subnumber := Sum(List(Filtered(cycsubs,X->IdGroup(Representative(X))=K),Size));
                Add(vallist,[K,subnumber]);
            od;

            Add(testlist,vallist);
        od;

    truthvals := List(testlist, L->Size(Filtered(testlist,M->M=L))>1);

    if ForAny(truthvals,X->X) then Print(n, "\n") ; break; fi;
od;
```

It'll simply print out the value $n$ if $S_n$ has non-isomorphic subgroups which have the same number of cyclic groups of every order.  In this case, it prints out nothing. So we have a lower bound $n\geq 8$, and thus $n=8$ is the answer.

Note the first definition of `subgroups` excludes $S_n$ and $A_n$--these subgroups are the unique subgroups of their order in $S_n$, so we may safely exclude them.  This has the added advantage of making sure that all calls to `IdGroup` will be valid: $A_7$ and $S_7$ are not covered by the `SmallGroups` package, and therefore using `IdGroup` on them would result in errors.  With them safely excluded, all groups that occur work with `IdGroup`, which is all we need to determine isomorphism types.